# How do I clear this history, it keeps reappearing any time I open git bash

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash

[my git bash preview anytime I open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvEOO.png)

I am unable to clear it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As a general rule of thumb: prefer pasting *text* rather than images. You can easily copy the content of a terminal window, and in SO use the "code block" (`{}` button) in stack overflow editor to have it displayed as a fixed size block

Answer (score 0):

You have some script, probably a `.bashrc` file, running when you open a `git-bash` instance. And it looks like it turns on the "echo" mode (perhaps there is a `set -x` command in it ?) and prints out the commands it executes.

Check if you have a `.bashrc` file, possibly hidden, in your home directory, and edit it with a text editor.